# Salesforce Console feed view is not showing the left sidebar details

Tags: feed-based-layout

we have enabled feed based layout for one of the page layouts of the custom objects and we have added the some information at left side bar component on  "custom console components" page and in the mini page layout also we checked some information to be displayed.we have added this page layout in the "page layout assignment" to associate the created layout to particular record type. The same functionality is working in one org but not in the other org.could anybody help us..

Comment: First we need to do the task of enabling feed based layout then try to create the console then it will not create this problem. we have done other way,thats caused the problem.